# Real time progress bar in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I made a progress bar to show the status of uploaded data.  I used web services and javascript but I got a problem. It is ever late web services than file save function. Thus, the information is not real in client side. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requests for a particular session are queued, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318965/asp-net-session-request-queuing/4319204#4319204).
That's why you can't upload and check how much has arrived at the same time.